# How to get latitude and longitude separately in 2 textviews in android studio JAVA?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, geolocation

from this i'm getting latitude and longitude in a single textview. But I want the latitude to be in 1 textview and longitude in another text view. Please help me on this.

My main activity

```
    package com.shopping.myapplication;

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button addressButton;
    TextView addressTV;
    TextView latLongTV;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        addressTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.addressTV);
       

        addressButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addressButton);

        addressButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addressET);
                String address = editText.getText().toString();

                GeocodingLocation locationAddress = new GeocodingLocation();
                locationAddress.getAddressFromLocation(address,
                        getApplicationContext(), new GeocoderHandler());
            }
        });

    }

    private class GeocoderHandler extends Handler {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message message) {
            String locationAddress;
            switch (message.what) {
                case 1:
                    Bundle bundle = message.getData();
                    locationAddress = bundle.getString("address");
                    break;
                default:
                    locationAddress = null;
            }
            latLongTV.setText(locationAddress);
        }
    }
    }
```

my geocodinglocation class.java

```
    package com.shopping.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class GeocodingLocation {

    private static final String TAG = "GeocodingLocation";

    public static void getAddressFromLocation(final String locationAddress,
                                              final Context context, final Handler handler) {
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
                String result = null;

                try {
                    List
                            addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locationAddress, 1);
                    if (addressList != null && addressList.size() > 0) {
                        Address address = (Address) addressList.get(0);
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();



                        sb.append(address.getLatitude()).append("\n");
                        sb.append(address.getLongitude()).append("\n");
                        result = sb.toString();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Unable to connect to Geocoder", e);
                } finally {
                    Message message = Message.obtain();
                    message.setTarget(handler);
                    if (result != null) {
                        message.what = 1;
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        result = "Address: " + locationAddress +
                                "\n\nLatitude and Longitude :\n" + result;
                        bundle.putString("address", result);
                        message.setData(bundle);
                    } else {
                        message.what = 1;
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        result = "Address: " + locationAddress +
                                "\n Unable to get Latitude and Longitude for this address location.";
                        bundle.putString("address", result);
                        message.setData(bundle);
                    }
                    message.sendToTarget();
                }
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

from this i'm getting latitude and longitude in a single textview. But I want the latitude to be in 1 textview and longitude in another text view. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but it appears that you are getting lat long as a single string for the address. Inside `run()` method for the thread, there are these lines:

```
sb.append(address.getLatitude()).append("\n");
sb.append(address.getLongitude()).append("\n");
result = sb.toString();
```

As you can see, you can get latitued and longitude from the address object here directly! There are many ways you can go about this. You can stick the lat and long values into the bundle if you wish. According to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address#getLatitude()), `getLatitude()` and `getLongitude()` return `double`:

```
public double getLatitude()
```

You could try putting the values independantly into the bundle, and give them appropriate keys. Or, if you don't want to mess with the geo code, you could in `onCreate()` method simply do:

```
String address = editText.getText().toString();
String[] values = address.split("\\n"); //we know that we need to split by \\n because we did sb.append(address.getLatitude()).append("\n")
//N.b: make sure to include \\n double backslash!
String lat = values[0];
String long = values[1];
```

Hope this helps! Please let me know if this works :D

EDIT: I have tried implementing it myself and it seems to work no problem! Here is a screenshot: [image]

Here is main activity:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.location.Address;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button addressButton;
    TextView addressTV;
    TextView latTV;
    TextView longTV;
    EditText editText;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        addressTV = findViewById(R.id.addressTV);
        latTV = findViewById(R.id.latTV);
        longTV = findViewById(R.id.longTV);
        addressButton = findViewById(R.id.addressButton);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addressET);

        addressButton.setOnClickListener(arg0 -> {
            String address = editText.getText().toString();

            GeocodingLocation locationAddress = new GeocodingLocation();
            locationAddress.getAddressFromLocation(address,
                    getApplicationContext(), new GeocoderHandler());
        });
    }

    private class GeocoderHandler extends Handler {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message message) {
            switch (message.what) {
                case 1:
                    Bundle bundle = message.getData();
                    Address address = bundle.getParcelable("address");
                    latTV.setText(address.getLatitude()+"");
                    longTV.setText(address.getLongitude()+"");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    addressTV.setText("unable to get address");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Notes: I simplified some things here for you, but its essentially the same. Important point however is that you can stick `Parcable` objects directly into the bundle, and since `Address` objects are `Parcable`, you can put the `Address` object directly into the bundle!

Here is the geo coding location class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class GeocodingLocation {

    private static final String TAG = "GeocodingLocation";

    public static void getAddressFromLocation(final String locationAddress,
                                              final Context context, final Handler handler) {
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
                Message message = Message.obtain();
                message.setTarget(handler);

                try {
                    List addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locationAddress, 1);
                    if (addressList != null && addressList.size() > 0) {
                        Address address = (Address) addressList.get(0);

                        message.what = 1;
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putParcelable("address", address);
                        message.setData(bundle);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "IOException", e);
                    message.what = 2;
                }
                message.sendToTarget();
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

Note: here I simplified your code a little bit also. Personally (and I think most people will agree), I like to code in a way that uses least indentations, but is still interpretable. Instead of doing `try catch finally` I just placed the correct pieces of code in `try` and `catch` separately, so there is no longer the need for `finally` clause at all.

Before you had a message with address string, and in the catch clause you would put the string "unable to get address for location" into bundle with key "address":

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
result = "Address: " + locationAddress +
         "\n\nLatitude and Longitude :\n" + result;
bundle.putString("address", result);
```

The `result` string doesn't contain an address, but rather an error message, so its probably not a good idea to put it in bundle with "address" key (because its an error message). I did it slightly differently, I set message.what property to `message.what = 2;`, and made that a `case` in the `switch` inside the main activity.

I hope this helps you further! :D

Comment: It's confusion. How can I implement this in my code. It's throwing errors :(

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes dude it did. Thanks for the help. It's working fine now :)

Comment: Glad to help my friend!